# Getting error on running the trained Machine Learning model

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I have a dataset containing columns 'studentDetails' and 'studentId'. I trained my model on this dataset and saved it. When I am training the model and saving the trained model, then loading the trained model to predict, it successfully giving me the output. But when I am loading the saved model standalone and predicting using that, it is giving me an error "CountVectorizer - Vocabulary wasn't fitted"

Here is the code I am using:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
import pickle
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC 

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df['studentDetails'], df['studentId'], random_state = 0)
count_vect = CountVectorizer()
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(X_train)
tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
X_train_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X_train_counts) 
classificationModel = LinearSVC().fit(X_train_tfidf, y_train) 
filename = 'finalized_model.sav'
pickle.dump(classificationModel, open(filename, 'wb'))
```

Now loading the model and predicting:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
data_to_be_predicted="Alicia Scott is from United States"
filename = 'finalized_model.sav'
loaded_model = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))
count_vect = CountVectorizer()
result = loaded_model.predict(count_vect.transform([data_to_be_predicted]))
print(result)
```

output:

```
94120
```

When I am running just the second code snippet standalone, it is giving me an error

error:

```
CountVectorizer - Vocabulary wasn't fitted
```

I am just wondering, how come I am getting an error in the second case because I am not redefining the count_vect = CountVectorizer() anywhere in the first case when I am getting the correct result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the second snippet is that you are not using the fitted CounVectorizer, its a new one so it is not fitted.

I will suggets you use **fit** instead of **fit_transform**, this will return you a CountVectorizer already fitted and then you can save it as you do with your model.

```
 from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
 from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
 from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
 import pickle
 from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC 

 X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df['studentDetails'], df['studentId'], random_state = 0)
 count_vect = CountVectorizer().fit(X_train)
 X_train_counts = count_vect.transform(X_train)
 tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer().fit(X_train_counts)
 X_train_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.transform(X_train_counts) 
 classificationModel = LinearSVC().fit(X_train_tfidf, y_train) 
 filename = 'finalized_model.sav'
 pickle.dump(classificationModel, open(filename, 'wb'))
 pickle.dump(count_vect, open('count_vect, 'wb'))
 pickle.dump(tfidf_transformer, open('tfidf_transformer, 'wb'))
```

And now you can load the 3 of them when you want to do predictions:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
data_to_be_predicted="Alicia Scott is from United States"
filename = 'finalized_model.sav'
loaded_model = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))
count_vect = pickle.load(open('count_vect', 'rb'))
result = loaded_model.predict(count_vect.transform([data_to_be_predicted]))
print(result)
```

Comment: Is this line necessary count_vect = CountVectorizer()?

Comment: Thanks i forgot to delete it from the original code.